# akka.actor.deployment confgure dynamic routees.paths

Tags: akka.net

```
akka {
   actor{
      provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
      deployment {
        /user/OrderBookCoordinatorActor/OrderBookActor-* {
          router = round-robin-pool # routing strategy
          routees.paths = ["/user/OrderBookCoordinatorActor"]
          nr-of-instances = 10 # max number of total routees
          cluster {
             enabled = on
             allow-local-routees = on
             use-role = crawler
             max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 1
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I have a problem that i need to match dynamic actors.

My code should be like

```
var path = "akka.tcp://OrderBook@127.0.0.1:8082/user/OrderBookCoordinatorActor/OrderBookActor-{ticker}"

var actor = Context.ActorSelection(path);
actor.Tell(removeOrder);
```

but I would like to achieve this with deployment and without enter whole TCP always. With ActorSelection like

```
var actor = Context.ActorSelection("/user/OrderBookCoordinatorActor" + ticker);
actor.Tell(removeOrder);
```

But the problem is that my Ticker is dynamic and can always change. How can I do this with deployment configuration?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/) which allows to route messages to actors living on different nodes without specifying any details about the node itself.